# Mac OSX (El Capitan) Virtual Hosts - challenge configuring custom virtual hosts

Tags: apache, localhost, virtualhost, osx-elcapitan

I configured local apache server on my mac. I want to configure custom virtual hosts ex: project1.local etc...

**I can access localhost which root folder is by default** /Library/WebServer/Documents

**I created new folder inside of document folder**
/Library/WebServer/Documents/typo3project

**Than I included in the /etc/apache2/httpd.conf**:
Include /private/etc/apache2/vhosts/*.conf

**And inside vhosts I created custom virtual hosts config file:**
typo3project.local.conf

I am getting 403 error (You don't have permission to access.... on this server.)

I set permissions to the folder: drwxr-xr-x

typo3project.local.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/typo3knjiga/" 
    ServerName typo3knjiga.test 
    <Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents/typo3knjiga"> 
        AllowOverride All 
        Require all granted 
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Show us the contents of `typo3project.local.conf`.  What is the owner/group of the folder?

Comment: here is content of typo3project.local.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/typo3knjiga/"
        ServerName typo3knjiga.test

<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents/typo3knjiga">
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

Comment: What is the owner/group of the folder?

Comment: owner is my username and group is admin

Comment: And just to be sure, what URL are you trying to access, `http://typo3knjiga.test/` ?  Is there an index.html or .php, and what are the ownership/permissions on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your vhost config does not specify a `DirectoryIndex`.  If Options Indexes is not enabled, that could cause a 403, as there is no allowable resource to return when you request `http://typo3knjiga.test/`.  Assuming you have an index.html or index.php, try adding the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

BTW you do not mention it, but I am assuming you have already added a record to your `/etc/hosts` file, like:

```
127.0.0.1 typo3knjiga.test
```

Comment: Hey, this works, thank you for your help!
P.S. but now I have another problem, as seems that my php doesnt work.

In the file typo3knjiga.test/index.php I entered php info function but browser just displays pure code ?